# flask socket io not working ( windows 7 & 10 ) anaconda and python 3.7

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io

I'm still a newbie in Development ( please don't rate down my post i've reached out everywhere to find a solution for the past 5 days )
 , I had only two projects as a tutorial 
in the second project i had to use Socket IO with flask but its not working 
- if my code doesnt have socket io in it and i ran `flask run` it output the following :

```
D:\WORK\study sc5\project1\project1>flask run
Serving Flask app "hello"
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

if it has socket io in it :

```
D:\WORK\study sc5\project2\project2>flask run
 * Serving Flask-SocketIO app "application"
```

**when i visited 127.0.0.1:5000 i found the server running so i ignored that it doesn't print `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` and kept going tell i made the first test to see if socket io can print and i have noticed everything prints just fine but socket io

I've asked my class mates , made ticket on github for 5 days we couldn't solve this
and i have tried on 2 machines ( home windows 10 and work place windows 7 ) both resulting the same thing

i made 2 videos about it ( i'll try to share them here if i'm allowed )

the .py files only have the following

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "sdfsdfssefe"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Project 2: TODO"
```

---

systems i have this with 
1- windows 10 - anacanda 
2- windows 7 - anacanda

things i have tried so far :

- updating anaconda
- eventlet
- gevent
- uninstalling anaconda
- reinstalling a newer version of anaconda
- uninstalling anaconda again
- installing python 3.7
- installing all required to run project 1
  import os , passlib,requests

  from flask import Flask, session , render_template , request from

  flask_session import Session from sqlalchemy import create_engine

  from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker from

  passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
- instaling eventlet with python 3.7
- installing cgywin
- testing server on cgywin

**results  all the same**
**except**

> now after cgywin and python 3.7 when i tried to run my own version of
>   project 2 which used to run smoothly but doesn't print anything from
>   socket io - it now says ( can't import application.py )

**pip freeze**

- certifi==2018.8.24
- chardet==3.0.4
- Click==7.0
- dnspython==1.15.0
- eventlet==0.24.1
- Flask==1.0.2
- Flask-Session==0.3.1
- Flask-SocketIO==3.0.2
- greenlet==0.4.15
- idna==2.7
- itsdangerous==0.24
- Jinja2==2.10
- MarkupSafe==1.0
- monotonic==1.5
- passlib==1.7.1
- psycopg2==2.7.5
- python-engineio==2.3.1
- python-socketio==2.0.0
- requests==2.19.1
- six==1.11.0
- SQLAlchemy==1.2.12
- urllib3==1.23
- virtualenv==16.0.0
- virtualenv-api==2.1.16
- Werkzeug==0.14.1

I've open ticket on course group , github and videos to demonstrate what happens if anyone could explain how i can upload them i will do edit the post and share them

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/807 ( i've also posted videos in the latest comments  )

Answer (score 0):

Does this work better?

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Project 2: TODO"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "sdfsdfssefe"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```